# Deriving an unknown matrix in an equation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm working on reverse-engineering a software system doing some computer graphics math. I've wound up in a weird situation where the following math is coming up:

M * X * M^-1 * A = B

Where M is a 3x3 constant invertible matrix, M^-1 is the inverse of M, X is a 3x3 matrix I can control, A is a 3x1 column vector I can also control. B is measurable.

How can I find what M is? I'm pretty sure that I could find the answer by expanding out all matrix components algebraically into a few massive equations - but it sure *feels* like there should be a more straightforward mechanism.

Comment: This question mostly belongs to [Mathematics.SE]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the [Eigendecomposition of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).

> [image: fig1]
>
> where the matrix **A** is decomposed into a diagonal matrix **Λ** and a vector of eigenvectors **Q**.

In your case you have

**C** = (**M**  **X** **M**<sup>-1</sup>)

If you can confirm that indeed **X** in your case is a diagonal matrix, then you know **M** to be the eigenvectors of **C**. You can get **C** from **C** = **A**<sup>-1</sup> **B**

As far as finding the eigenvectors, even for 3×3 matrices, is a genuinely hard problem. Typically you do a [Shur Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) and recover the eigevectors.

I did find an online resource for the 3×3 problem, which I ported into `C#` for an other project. [Original source here](https://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/personalhomes/globes/3x3/index.html).

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the three eigenvalues analytically.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Code taken from:
/// https://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/personalhomes/globes/3x3/index.html
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>A vector containing the three eigenvalues.</returns>
public Vector3 GetEigenValues()
{
    //      Determine coefficients of characteristic polynomial. We write
    //      | A   D   F  |
    // A =  | D*  B   E  |
    //      | F*  E*  C  |

    var de = data.m_12 * data.m_23;
    var dd = data.m_12 * data.m_12;
    var ee = data.m_23 * data.m_23;
    var ff = data.m_13 * data.m_13;
    var m = data.m_11 + data.m_22 + data.m_33;
    var c1 = (data.m_11 * data.m_22 + data.m_11 * data.m_33 + data.m_22 * data.m_33) - (dd + ee + ff);
    var c0 = data.m_33 * dd + data.m_11 * ee + data.m_22 * ff - data.m_11 * data.m_22 * data.m_33 - 2.0 * data.m_13 * de;

    var p = m * m - 3.0 * c1;
    var q = m * (p - (3.0 / 2.0) * c1) - (27.0 / 2.0) * c0;
    var sqrt_p = (float) Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(p));

    var sqrt_z = (float) Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(27.0 * (0.25 * c1 * c1 * (p - c1) + c0 * (q + 27.0 / 4.0 * c0))));
    var phi = (1 / 3f) * (float) Math.Atan2(sqrt_z, q);

    var c = sqrt_p * (float) Math.Cos(phi);
    var s = sqrt_p * (float)( Math.Abs(Math.Sin(phi))/ Math.Sqrt(3));

    var w = (1 / 3f) * (m - c);

    // sort the eigenvalues
    if (c >= s)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            w - s,
            w + s,
            w + c);
    }
    else if (c >= -s)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            w - s,
            w + c,
            w + s);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Vector3(
            w + c,
            w - s,
            w + s);
    }
}

public Matrix3 GetEigenVectors() => GetEigenVectors(GetEigenValues());
public Matrix3 GetEigenVectors(Vector3 eigenValues)
{
    Vector3 ev1 = GetEigenVector(eigenValues.X).Unit();
    Vector3 ev2 = GetEigenVector(eigenValues.Y).Unit();
    Vector3 ev3 = GetEigenVector(eigenValues.Z).Unit();

    return FromColumns(ev1, ev2, ev3);
}
Vector3 GetEigenVector(float w)
{
    return new Vector3(
          data.m_12 * (data.m_23 - data.m_33 + w) - data.m_13 * (data.m_22 - data.m_23 - w)
        + data.m_22 * (data.m_33 - w) - data.m_23 * data.m_23 - w * (data.m_33 - w),
        -data.m_11 * (data.m_23 - data.m_33 + w) + data.m_12 * (data.m_13 - data.m_33 + w)
        - data.m_13 * data.m_13 + data.m_13 * data.m_23 + w * (data.m_23 - data.m_33 + w),
          data.m_11 * (data.m_22 - data.m_23 - w) - data.m_12 * data.m_12 + data.m_12 * (data.m_13 + data.m_23)
        + data.m_13 * (w - data.m_22) - w * (data.m_22 - data.m_23 - w));
}
```

For your case you would do `M=C.GetEigenVectors();`

---

A final note here is that you can scale **M** up or down by a factor, and it wont change the equation since you are multiplying with **M** and **M**<sup>-1</sup> at the same time. So you just need to find *just one* of the infinite matrices **M** that would make this equation work.